# How to countermand a Barabarian's Rage ability?

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian

In D&D 5e, the Barbarian's Rage ability is quite powerful. The rulebook states that the only way to end a Rage against the user's will, is to either avoid any chance of him taking damage for a turn, avoid him attacking anyone for a turn, or knocking him out.

> ## Rage
>
> In battle, you fight with primal ferocity. On your turn, you can enter a rage as a bonus action. While raging, you gain the following benefits if you aren’t wearing heavy armor:
>
> - You have advantage on Strength checks and Strength saving throws.
> - When you make a melee weapon attack using Strength, you gain a +2 bonus to the damage roll.
> - You have resistance to bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage.
>
> During your rage, you cannot knock a creature out. If you are able to cast spells, you can’t cast them or concentrate on them while raging. Your rage lasts for 1 minute. **It ends early if you are knocked unconscious or if your turn ends and you haven’t attacked a creature since your last turn or taken damage since then.** You can also end your rage on your turn as a bonus action. Once you have raged 2 times, you must finish a long rest before you can rage again.

Is there any other way of ending the Rage against the user's will, other than avoiding combat?

**Edit:** For clarification, I'm asking for any ability that directly affects the Rage user, that will end the Rage, without employing anything that can be counted as avoiding an Attack from the Rage user, delivering an Attack to the Rage user, or dealing a KO to the Rage user, as specified in the rule itself.

Comment: What do you mean when you say avoiding combat?

Comment: Are you just looking for strategies to knock barbarians unconscious or otherwise prevent them from attacking or taking damage? Or are you looking for other ways of ending Rage than those listed in the ability?

Comment: @Miniman I am looking for other ways of ending Rage than those listed in the ability.

Comment: @PremierBromanov exactly what it means really. If the user makes a successful attack, or takes damage, the Rage continues. So I want to avoid being attacked, or attacking the user.

Comment: @Ben so, to be clear: you're looking for things other than listed. I.e. you want houserules for additions to the "Rage" description which have it end under other conditions?

Comment: I don't understand how the powers of a martial character are somehow viewed with fear and suspicion. FFS, a DM can provide a wide variety of challenges that overwhelm any group.  It Isn't That Hard.  To put it more bluntly, if you are the DM and the Barbarian is troubling you, turn in your DM card.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid combat with a raging barbarian, combat is upon you already. Are you against, say, casting a spell on him?

Comment: It would also help if we had some perspective to this "problem". are you a DM trying to control a character that is winning too hard, or something else?

Comment: @PremierBromanov this is from a player perspective

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're expecting, but there does not appear to be any item or spell that ends a Barbarian's Rage directly.

There are of course a multitude of items, spells, and even class features that can end a Rage indirectly, using one of the conditions listed in the Rage ability.

It might be worth noting that your bolded text does not include all of the conditions for ending a Rage - the Barbarian can end it themselves. So any of the many items, spells, or abilities that allow you to force someone to do something against their will should work. For example, if you successfully cast *Dominate Person* on a Barbarian, then you can command them to stop Raging and they will be forced to comply.

Comment: Depending on how the DM interprets it, something like Command would likely be sufficient to calm them. Even Color Spray would probably do it. There's a lot of options here that work indirectly.

Comment: So, effectively the only other options require you to be a magic user?

Comment: @user1673882 With the right command, sure. That's just another example of a spell that forces them to do something. I'm not sure how color spray could work, though - blindness has no effect on rage. In any case, as we both said, there are a multitude of options here, and there's no point trying to list them all out.

Comment: @Ben Not necessarily - there are plenty of magic items that would work and don't require a caster. For that matter, a mundane net could work, too.

Comment: @Ben Do you feel like visiting RPG General Chat? I get the impression I'm missing something with this question.

Answer (score 2):

I had to consider how to take out a barbarian a while back. I came down to 2 options.

1. Let him rage then back away from him. If he gains a level of exhaustion then even better. Prevent him from attacking.
2. Use the calm emotions spell. I think it might be up to the DM but I'm sure that would do it.